# Out-of-class definition of member of a class template with a class-type non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, g++, c++20, non-type

With C++20, it's possible to define a template class taking a [class-type non-type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter):

```cpp
struct A {};

template <A a>
struct B {
    void f();
};
```

But is it possible to define `B::f()` out-of-class like with integral types? Because this

```cpp
template <int>
struct C {
    void f();
};

template <int i>
void C<i>::f() {}
```

compiles, but this

```cpp
template <A a>
void B<a>::f() {}
```

yields an "invalid use of incomplete type" error when I try to compile it on gcc 9. Curiously, if I replace `B` to take a non-type parameter of `auto` instead of `A`, it compiles just fine:

```cpp
template <auto a>
struct B {
   void f();
};

template <auto a>
void B<a>::f() {}
```

I know support for C++20 is still experimental on gcc 9, but is this supposed to be possible or not?

Comment: The term is "non-type template parameter" not "template parameter object." And yes, this should work, filed [92776](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92776).

Comment: Dang, that was fast lmao. More precisely, it is "non-type template parameter of class type", I thought "template parameter object" was a synonym...

Comment: @SepiaColor: There *are* template parameter objects for non-type template parameters of class type, but they are distinct from the parameter itself which abstractly exists once for all specializations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code

```
template <auto a>
struct B {
   void f();
};

template <auto a>
void B<a>::f() {}
```

will compile in C++20. Please note that
the code

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
concept A = std::is_same<T,int>::value;

template <A a>
struct B {
   void f();
};

template <A a>
void B<a>::f() {}
```

will also compile in C++20, because A is a `concept`.